# XKB - Certain CTRL + SHIFT + Key combinations do not work when using CAPS LOCK as CTRL

Tags: kubuntu, xkb

Kubuntu 20.04

I created a new keyboard keymap using xkb and remapped the caps lock key as left control, however, a few keyboard combinations such as ctrl+shift+c and ctrl+shift+s do not work (have no output when using xev).

However, when I use the right control key, these shortcuts seem to work. They also work when control is mapped to another key (such as backspace). Intuitively, I tried remapping caps lock to right control but that does not work either and in fact makes the actual right control key not work either.

I suspect it is a problem with the keycodes, as mapping "c" to another key does not fix the issue, and the problem persists with other layouts as well, such as Colemak.

Here is the xkb source file with which I was able to reproduce the issue on another computer.

```
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "colemak-programmer" {

    include "pc"
    include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1]= "English (Programmer Colemak)";

    key <TLDE> { [        grave,       asciitilde           ] };
    key <AE01> { [            1,           exclam           ] };
    key <AE02> { [            2,               at           ] };
    key <AE03> { [            3,       numbersign           ] };
    key <AE04> { [            4,           dollar           ] };
    key <AE05> { [            5,          percent           ] };
    key <AE06> { [            6,      asciicircum           ] };
    key <AE07> { [            7,        ampersand           ] };
    key <AE08> { [            8,         asterisk           ] };
    key <AE09> { [            9,        parenleftquotemark  ] };
    key <AE10> { [            0,       parenrightequotemark ] };
    key <AE11> { [        minus,       underscore           ] };
    key <AE12> { [        equal,             plus           ] };

    key <AD01> { [            q,            Q ] };
    key <AD02> { [            w,            W ] };
    key <AD03> { [            f,            F ] };
    key <AD04> { [            p,            P ] };
    key <AD05> { [            b,            B ] };
    key <AD06> { [            j,            J ] };
    key <AD07> { [            l,            L ] };
    key <AD08> { [            u,            U ] };
    key <AD09> { [            y,            Y ] };
    key <AD10> { [    semicolon,        colon ] };
    key <AD11> { [  BackSpace ] };
    key <AD12> { [  BackSpace ] };
    key <BKSL> { [    backslash,          bar ] };

    key <AC01> { [            a,            A,          bracketleft   ] };
    key <AC02> { [            r,            R,          braceleft     ] };
    key <AC03> { [            s,            S,          equal         ] };
    key <AC04> { [            t,            T,          parenleft     ] };
    key <AC05> { [            g,            G,          asterisk      ] };
    key <AC06> { [            k,            K,          minus         ] };
    key <AC07> { [            n,            N,          parenright    ] };
    key <AC08> { [            e,            E,          underscore    ] };
    key <AC09> { [            i,            I,          braceright    ] };
    key <AC10> { [            o,            O,          bracketright  ] };
    key <AC11> { [   apostrophe,     quotedbl ] };

    key <AB01> { [            x,            X ] };
    key <AB02> { [            c,            C ] };
    key <AB03> { [            d,            D ] };
    key <AB04> { [            v,            V ] };
    key <AB05> { [        ISO_Level3_Shift    ] };
    key <AB06> { [            m,            M ] };
    key <AB07> { [            h,            H ] };
    key <AB08> { [        comma,         less ] };
    key <AB09> { [       period,      greater ] };
    key <AB10> { [        slash,     question ] };

    key <LSGT> { [        minus,   underscore ] };
    key <SPCE> { [        space,        space ] };
    key <CAPS> { [      Control_L             ] };
    key <BKSP> {   [       0,       BackSpace ] };
    key <LCTL> {  [ z, Z ] };

}; 

        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc101)"     };
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your release, there was no release of Kubuntu in 2020-February (20.02)

Comment: Tried some XKB option such as `ctrl:swapcaps`?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, I've tried that, but no avail.

Comment: Seems to work for me (checked gedit and gnome-terminal). Maybe you could be a bit more specific about the applications where the issue is present?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I updated my post; the issue is system-wide

Comment: Are you saying that it is with your customized keymap where `ctrl:swapcaps` doesn't work, while it works otherwise (as it does for me)? In that case you are asking the wrong question. The title of your question should rather be: "Need help to make customized keymap work as expected".

Comment: The problem is persistent on multiple layouts, not only mine. Given the nature of the problem in that only certain, specific combinations do not work and also that it only occurs when the shift is mapped to the caps lock key, it suggests that there is a more fundamental, os-related issue. @GunnarHjalmarsson